# Login to web site using c#

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am trying to login to one of our internal websites to using a small programme using HttpWebRequest. You can find the below code I found in [This Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4839918/logging-in-to-an-https-site-using-c-sharp#) to login to the website. Please find my changed code below according to our site.

```
class LoginSite
{
    CookieContainer Cookies = new CookieContainer();

   public void Main()
    {
        Login();

        // Now the cookies in "Cookies" are all set.
        // Ensure you set CookieContainer on all subsequent requests
    }

    void Login()
    {
        var wr = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://portal.test.com/Login.aspx");
        wr.Method = "POST";
        wr.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        wr.Referer = "http://portal.test.com/Login.aspx"; // my tests show this is needed
        wr.CookieContainer = Cookies;

        var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>{
        //{"__LASTFOCUS", ""},
        //{"__EVENTTARGET",""},
        // {"__EVENTARGUMENT",""},
        //{"__VIEWSTATE","INdS1F45fzWYVwKD8b1b5x5Mr09nYrvS3hrSO4EAXFHVwtN76gSoToydwoOlIf1nI+KIxVR5CWiN2c5NOPO7kjTW7DbiNG2ZZ5Mpd0pYvN3tt68I6MvZ1dGHMJFhgJQ1YYpQQ+V6oonOrncJ6lwk69LaPVuSUSAPSubgSBoNYLfEy28kHirrNNc0uburWHQ9DK0zHwwod8gWKS8sz+qSjWOzV0PZyX7HhMQjc4MAD+RkHQMgeyOMqghODYn2ZW5mCBcY34ISL328aPGZmb6XERo+9LArRwASFBNqyFygZ1YJaUwReOdceEpTtg6TEOJb"},
        //{"__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR", "A43BD702"},
        //{"__EVENTVALIDATION","ngIch5+O80dcLktVDBbT/QqkZ8TvAm/HNMQVR54bGv0oQRxd2LqBISWhjdwgvwjnbaGSBAFDFcuvCgmdBvAJ/eBUSCNB9vMGfPzhecbdCFcGVzKy7/d49KNK/f8D+QBrT912wDav1/LFqFn32Op+HVOj2qLwuuvRLF+v4NL/xhpu22QNXXO/B4r/OAYJgtFYlZCg1k4jO7QacNdjaoJ02KVj0xBm9fWbr02spbCUld7+fY9shCyEcthLpEag8OryqKQlYtDgx8UxCc6bj5GKQw=="},
        {"ctl00$cphBody$LogIn1$txtUserName", "testuser"},
        {"ctl00$cphBody$LogIn1$vceUserName_ClientState", ""},
        {"ctl00$cphBody$LogIn1$txtPassword", "testpwd"},
         {"ctl00$cphBody$LogIn1$vecPassword_ClientState", ""},
          {"ctl00$cphBody$LogIn1$btnSubmit", "Submit"}
    };

        using (var requestStream = wr.GetRequestStream())
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(requestStream, Encoding.UTF8))
            writer.Write(ParamsToFormEncoded(parameters));

        using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)wr.GetResponse())
        {
            // here you need to detect a correct login... this might be one of the cookies.
            // if incorrect throw an exception or something.
            using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
            {
              var  result = sr.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
    }

    string ParamsToFormEncoded(Dictionary<string, string> parameters)
    {
        return string.Join("&", parameters.Select(kvp =>
            Uri.EscapeDataString(kvp.Key).Replace("%20", "+") + "=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(kvp.Value).Replace("%20", "+")
        ).ToArray());
    }
}
```

I have added the exact form values into parameters, I did not get any exception while getting a response, but still cookies count i am getting is zero. Can any one help me out please i have already spend lot of time on this. Below is the screen shot of Form Data.[image]

Comment: What are you trying to do with the login, are you trying to use that login to test something or are you trying to authenticate yourself through another website? Both have very different answers :)

Comment: I want to scrap the website after logging in, i will use httpAgilitypack to scrap the webiste after logging into HomePage.aspx

Comment: Are you suppose to get a cookie?  Not all server will respond with a cookie, or the old cookie expired so the server doesn't send one.  Also if the request contains a cookie the server doesn't have to respond with a new cookie provided the old one did not expire.

Comment: @jdweng When i logged in manually to the site i can see the Set-Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId in Response headers, so i guess server is actually responding with a cookie ,IS this what u want to know? did i answered u or im missing anything

Comment: The issue is if you login manually the manual login will set the cookie on your PC.  So the app then login using the stored cookie and you will not get a cookie in the app response.  So if you want to see the cookie in the app delete the cookie manually before running the app.  I usually just go to my browser and delete all cookies.  The browser and the VS App both use the same user temp folder for the cookies.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to get a new cookie when uncommented LASTFocus,__EVENTTARGET,__EVENTARGUMENT,__VIEWSTATE,__VIEWSTATEGENERATOR,__EVENTVALIDATION and added wr.AllowAutoRedirect = false. But i did not get the new redirected page ie  http://portal.test.com/Home.aspx in response. Instead i am getting the response like Object moved

### Object moved to [here](/Home.aspx).